# Regex to return full string if pattern not matched

Tags: regex

I need a regex to interpret the data from a product barcode.

The following works for my use case:

```
(\w+)\^\^(\w+)\^(\w+)
```

with example barcode

```
PRODID^^BATCH^EXP
```

returning these three elements as separate groups.

What I would like is is a barcode is presented that is not in the `A^^B^C` format then the full string is returned as group one.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do this in the caller? If the regexp doesn't match, just use the full string as a default.

Comment: This regex is being used with a virtual wedge configuration on a handheld scanner. the full configuration string is (\w+)\^\^(\w+)\^(\w+)->\1\t\2 which allows for the first and second group to be passed to two seperate input boxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my take on it..

`^((?=\w+\^\^\w+\^\w+)\w+|.*)(?:\^\^(\w+)\^(\w+))?`

Group 1 makes use of positive lookahead to see if your `a^^b^c` format matches, and falls back to just matching all. Meanwhile, the additional `^^b^c` stuff is wrapped in a non-capturing group and made optional.

**demo** (thanks @Barmar !) https://regex101.com/r/tI7QV2/2

```
"a^^b^c"

Full match  0-6 `a^^b^c`
Group 1.    0-1 `a`
Group 2.    3-4 `b`
Group 3.    5-6 `c`

"abc"

Full match  0-3 `abc`
Group 1.    0-3 `abc`
```

Answer (score 2):

The logical choice is to use a *Branch Reset*

`(?m)^(?|(\w+)\^\^(\w+)\^(\w+)|(.+)()())$`

https://regex101.com/r/mFoOdW/3

Explained:

```
 # Barcode regex
 # -----------------------
 (?m)                          # Multi-line mode
 ^                             # Beginning of line
 (?|                           # Branch reset
      ( \w+ )                       # (1), Element 1
      \^\^
      ( \w+ )                       # (2), Element 2
      \^
      ( \w+ )                       # (3), Element 3
   |                              # or,
      ( .+ )                        # (1), Entire line
      ( )                           # (2), empty
      ( )                           # (3), empty
 )
 $                             # End of line
```

If you expect optional padded characters before/after the elements,
you could use it with this modification instead.

`(?m)^(?|.*?(\w+)\^\^(\w+)\^(\w+).*?|(.+)()())$`

https://regex101.com/r/mFoOdW/4